# Is there a way to wait for a command to be executed, before executing a new command in the same instance of a program

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, wait

I´m reading out runtime-information of machines. My problem is, that the subprocess instance is closed, after i successfully connected to the machine, and before my command, to read the runtime data, is executed.

I already wrote both commands in one line:

```
    constr =    [program, "connect", "-I", "192.168.0.75", "runinfo", "T", "R"]
```

Resulting in only the connection was established before the shell was closed.

I tried it with the code in one string:

```
    constr =    [program, "connect -I  "192.168.0.75" "runinfo" "T" "R"]
```

Resulting in the shell staying open, but not connecting or doing anything at all.

I also tried seperation of the two commands with seperators like:

```
    |    &   ;
```

without any success.

My Code right now:

```
import subprocess

#Path to the programm
program = "../../../../Program Files (x86)/HEIDENHAIN/TNCremo/TNCcmdPlus.exe"

#command to connect
constr =    [program, "connect", "-I", "192.168.0.75"]

# command to read the runtime
getstr  =    ["runinfo", "T", "R"]

# execute subprocess
subprocess.Popen(constr, shell=False)
```

As you can see I don´t use the second command at all right now. Because of my lack of success so far.

I would love to get the same result, like when using the TNCcmdPlus.exe shell.

```
Local:C:\Users\****\Desktop> connect -I 192.168.0.75
Serial cable (P), Ethernet (I) or Local (L): —l
Serial port (e.g. COM2): 192.168.0.75
Connecting with 192.168.0.75...‚ 0 Band
Connection established with iTNC530. NC Software 340422 14 SP5
TNC:\> runinfo I R
Info type: T
Nc up eine (N). Machine up time (M), Machine running tine (R) or
PLC operation times (0..1) : R
Machine running time: 49404289 sec (571 days 19 h 24 min 40 sec)
TNC:\>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got things right, you need [[Python 3]: Popen.**communicate**(*input=None, timeout=None*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) (or `Popen.wait`), in order to wait for a process to terminate, before spawning the other one, something like:

```py
# ...
# execute subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(constr)
p.communicate()
p = subprocess.Popen(getstr)
p.communicate()
```

As a note, you could also use one of the convenience functions (e.g. `subprocess.check_output`).

Comment: I tried that already. The problem was, that it closes the shell after every command i execute.

Comment: Like what? the shell prompt?